# Unexpected compiler warning

Tags: c, format-specifiers

How to remove this warning?

> `warning: format '%d' expects argument of type ' int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=] printf(“%d”,p1->j);`

Here's the code, everything works fine except for the warning.

```
void main()
{
    struct s1
    {
        int *j;
    };

    struct s2
    {
        int k;
    };
    struct s1 *p1;
    struct s2 *p2;

    p1=malloc(sizeof(struct s1));
    p2=malloc(sizeof(struct s2));
    p2->k=5;
    p1->j=&p2->k;
    printf("%d",p1->j);
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d",p1->j);`->`printf("%d",*(p1->j));`

Comment: Is the code for some exercise in learning pointers? Because none of it makes any other sense.

Comment: You really should be able to understand such a warning without outside help. Read that warning carefully. BTW `malloc` can fail and you should test that

Comment: It is not a programming problem OP needs a C book

Comment: How about testing the `malloc`s' results _and_ `free`-ing allocated structures after use...?

Answer (score 1):

`j` is of type `int*` when used here : `printf("%d",p1->j);`, `printf` doesn't like that and wants an `int` so you should dereference :

```
printf("%d",*(p1->j));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below statements

```
p1->j=&p2->k; /* check the operator precedence */
```

should be

```
p1->j=&(p2->k); /* j is type of ptr, it should hold address of k variable */
```

Also while accessing 
`printf("%d",p1->j);` -> `printf("%d",*(p1->j));` Because `p1->j` yields in  address not value.

Comment: Could you elaborate on &p2->k and (&p2)->k ,what I understand is &p2->k gives actual address of where value of k is stored where as (&p2)->k gives address of p2 . Or am I wrong ?

Comment: As `->` having higher priority than `&`, it  solve `p2->k` first which is not the actual intention.

Comment: My  intention was to get address of k

Comment: @bbcbbc1 then it should be `&(p2->k)`

Comment: @achal you got it backwards, `&p2->k` is fine.